# Compile assembly from 64 to m32 ld error

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm interesting in compile a 32bit assembly code using a 64bit machine.

This is the 32 bit code:

```
.global factorial

factorial:
    pushl %ebp          
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp       
      pushl %esi
      pushl %ebx

    movl $1,-4(%ebp)
    movl $2,%esi
for:  
      cmpl 8(%ebp), %esi
    jg endfor
      movl -4(%ebp), %ebx
      imull %esi, %ebx
      movl  %ebx, -4(%ebp)
    incl %esi   

    jmp for
endfor:
      movl -4(%ebp), %eax   

    popl %ebx       
    popl %esi   
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp   
    ret
```

I'm building:

```
> gcc test32.s -m32 -o test32
```

But I'm obtaining:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib32/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

know someone who's going? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have a main function, or anything that looks like it. What would you expect the resulting executable to do?

Comment: thanks for the response Mat. But this is not the issue. This program is only for debugging propose (ddd). It works in a 32 bit machine

Comment: You don't have a program there. You only have one function. You can't compile it into an executable, whatever platform you're compiling on is.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry
I made a big mistake.
I've crossed two codes. You are right. Sorry!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compile and link to an executable. For that to work, you need a `main` function that contains the programs start function.

All you have is a single mathematical function, without any way to define inputs and outputs.

Comment: Hi Simon. I know, isn't a complet program only to debug with ddd. I tested in a 32bit machine and works ok, the problem is compiling in 64 bit machine to obtain the 32 bit

Comment: Sorry sorry,
All of you are right. I made a great error.

Sorry again.